# HTML Helper/Text Box validation

Tags: .net, jquery, html-helper

I have this input on the view:

```
<%= Html.TextBoxCurrentDateWithoutPermission("EffectiveDate", Model.EffectiveDate.HasValue ? Model.EffectiveDate.Value.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") : "", new string[] { PERMISSIONS.hasICAdvanced }, new { @class = "economicTextBox", propertyName = "EffectiveDate", onchange = "parseAndSetDt(this); ", dataType = "Date" })%>
```

Here is the custom HTML Helper:

```
public static MvcHtmlString TextBoxCurrentDateWithoutPermission(
                                                          this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
                                                          string name,
                                                          object value,
                                                          string[] permissions,
                                                          object htmlAttributes
                                                         )
        {
            foreach (string permission in permissions)
            {
                if (Chatham.Web.UI.Extranet.SessionManager.DisplayUser.IsInRole(permission))
                {
                    // the user has the permission => render the textbox
                    return htmlHelper.TextBox(name, value, htmlAttributes);
                }
            }

            // the user has no permission => render a readonly checkbox
            var mergedHtmlAttributes = new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes);
            mergedHtmlAttributes["disabled"] = "disabled";
            return htmlHelper.TextBox(name, value == "" ? DateTime.Now : value, mergedHtmlAttributes);
        }
```

The way this works now is, when a user does NOT have the permission passed in, the box is disabled.

The way it needs to be -- if the user does NOT have the permission passed in, it needs to be enabled, however the only dates it can accept are todays date AND dates in the future.

So I need JQuery validation (or just plain JS), for this textbox on the page for the following case:

If the textbox is enabled AND the user does not have the permission, allow the user to input the current date or future dates ONLY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using JQuery's .validate() method.